# Is this quotient manifold a Klein bottle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, surfaces

Consider the torus $T=\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3| (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2)^2+z^2=1\}\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and the action of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ on $T$ given by $\hat{a}+(x, y, z)=\left(\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)x-\sin\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)y, \sin\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)x + \cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)y, z\right)$. I am asked to describe the quotient manifold $T/\mathbb{Z}_4$ (well, I am asked to prove first that the action is free and properly discontinuous, but that is easy since we are acting by a finite group and I only need to check for fixed points, which is really simple in this case).

I believe that this is a Klein bottle. Let me explain my reasoning. What our action does is basically to encode a rotation matrix in the $xy$-plane. Trying to picture this in my head, what I get by gluing the points accordingly is nothing but a Klein bottle. I know this is no way a rigorous proof. I would also be interested in that, but first and foremost I want to know if my heuristic answer is correct.

Comment: Your intuition is half correct. If you reverse one edge the fundamental polygon of a torus it's a Klein bottle. If I reverse the same edge of any fundamental polygon twice I get the same fundamental polygon.  Thankfully the action is free and properly discontinuous so the orbits are relatively easy to examine. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Isn't this map just rotating the torus multiples of 90 degrees? Or am I misreading? That sounds like a quadruple-cover of another torus

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes, that's what I had in mind. So, basically what I am getting is just another torus?

Comment: @CyclotomicField thanks for your input, I hadn't thought about fundamental polygons like this. So, I guess that I should be getting just another torus (or basically just the same one since we are just rotating our torus)?

Comment: I believe @AkivaWeinberger is right and this a quadruple cover of the torus. It's sort of like cutting the torus into a tube then gluing the ends together to form a new torus. The four chunks collapse into a single one due to the quotient.

Comment: Wait I misread I thought Ted posted this question lol